# angular2 ionic2 how execute animation from component and bind data

Tags: angular, ionic2

I have Component with contain images, and I wan't add to it swipe animation like tinder.

How Can I provide deltaX (from event) to animation.
 in jquery it will somthing like :

```
$card.css("transform", "translateX("+ pullDeltaX +"px) rotate("+ deg +"deg)");
```

How it make in angular2?

My code:

```
<ion-card 
        (swipe)="gradeProfile($event)"
        (pan)="panEvent($event)"
        @StateItem="state" 
        class="active-card card"
        >
        <img [src]="selectedProduct?.image_path" />

    </ion-card>
    <ion-card class="inactive-card card" >
        <img *ngIf="products.length" [src]="products[products.length - 1]?.image_path" />
    </ion-card>
```

component:

```
@Component({
templateUrl: 'build/pages/picker/picker.html',
animations: [
    trigger('StateItem', [
        state('initState', style({
            transform: 'translate(0)',
            opacity: 1
        })),
        state('moveState', style({
        })),
        state('moveLike', style({
            transform: 'translate(10vw) rotate(10deg)',
        })),
...
panEvent(event) {
```

.... //to do call transform(event.deltaX) animation

Comment: I fix this problem modified style on element
    
    activeCartSetTranslation(target, deltaX, rotation, translationUnits = 'px') {
    target.style.transform = `translate3d(${deltaX}${translationUnits}, 0px, 0px) rotate(${rotation}deg)`;
  }


aftere change state of animation  the element style is set to style from trigger